# Redirect to a different page depending on the multiple options selected

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm hoping someone can help me. I'm creating a form with two questions. Question 1 is where are you located with three different options (New York, California, Maryland) then a second question "What are you eating tonight" with four different options (Lobster, Steak, Crab, Salmon). Based on what the users respond to, they get sent to a unique landing page (each URL will be different). I was able to find this code, but it only works for one dropdown question, whereas I need code that would be good for a unique combination of both dropdowns. I couldn't find this answer anywhere, and I was hoping someone could give me some insight.

````
<!-- Insert in Settings->Javascript->Header -->
<!-- CS:20200120-11-1 -->
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    function pageGenerator(fieldName) {
        return window.__page_generator ? fieldName : base64_encode(fieldName);
    }

    var dropdownName = "My Dropdown"; // Field name
    var options = {
        "Option 1": "https://instapage.com", // Each option on a new line
        "Option 2": "https://help.instapage.com/hc",
        "Option 3": "https://help.instapage.com/hc/en-us/articles/214133067"
        // "Option Name" : "Redirect URL if this option is chosen"
    }

    var selectInput = document.querySelectorAll('form select[name="' + pageGenerator(dropdownName) + '"]');

    window.instapageFormSubmitSuccess = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < selectInput.length; i++) {
            var selectedOption = selectInput[i].value;
            document.querySelectorAll('input[name="redirect"]')[i].value = options[selectedOption];
        }
    }
});
</script>
<!-- End "Redirect depending on dropdown" || Help center -->```
````

Comment: So the user will select New York, then select steak.  Based on those two combined selections, they will be redirected to a URL?

Comment: I'm missing the part that describes which URL they get sent to, because if the url is "the same URL but with the location and mealtype bits differing per choice" then that's a very different exercise from "any random url for each possible combination".

Comment: Hi John, that is exactly it! But if they select New York & Lobster - they go to a different page

Comment: Hi Mike, The URL would need to be unique for every combination:
- New York, Lobster
- New York, Steak
- New York, Crab
- New York, Salmon
- Maryland, Lobster
- Maryland, Steak
- Maryland, Crab
- Maryland, Salmon

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, [**THIS**](https://gist.github.com/Omkaragrawal/8c5c8b550f8258ad7a1c53dc685ef455)  is a solution that came up with.

[**CODEPEN link**](https://codepen.io/omkaragrawal/pen/QWbQQby) (so that you can execute.)

index.html:

```
<select id="State">


<option disabled selected> default</option>
  <option> NY</option>
  <option> CA</option>
  <option> MD</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select id="food" hidden>
  <option disabled selected> default</option>
  <option> Lobster</option>
  <option> Steak</option>
  <option> Crab</option>
  <option> Salmon</option>
</select>

<script>
let string = ["", ""];

document.getElementById("food").addEventListener("change", event => {
  console.log(event);
  string[1] = event.target.value;
  // document.body.innerText += event.target.value;
  window.location.href += "/" + string.join("-");
});

document.getElementById("State").addEventListener("change", event => {
  // document.body.innerText += event.target.value;
  console.log(event);
  string[0] = event.target.value;
  document.getElementById("food").hidden = false;
});
```

## *Note:*

**1. You can manipulate the location anyhow you wish by using "window.location.href" I 
      have used here to continue on the same path.**

**2. I have kept constant format, that is first the state then " - " and finally food. You can change it to your preference (such as "/state/food" or "/food/state, etc)**

**3 If you use the codepen then it will redirect to give you an 404 error**